# Deceptive landscapes for a Genetic Algorithm

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I am currently doing a project on genetic algorithms and what makes it hard for them to be solved. For this project I am required to generate a population of binary strings and get the fitness of each individual.

The fitness function should give a string with all 1s be the best fitness value, a string with all 0s the second best values and then any variation of 0s and 1s should return a worse value if there are more 1s (unless all 1s) and a better value the more zeros.

My project requires me to compare the performance of the GA with a binary alphabet to a decimal alphabet. For the decimal alphabet I was able to create a deceptive fitness function by assigning weights to each number 9 being the best, 8 worst and as you get to 0 increasing in value. This leads the GA away from the optimal solution providing a deceptive landscape.

If you have any advice on a binary deceptive fitness function that would be great. I have included my fitness function for the decimal alphabet:

```
public float getFitness(){
    fitness= 0.00f;
    for(int j =0;j<genes.length;j++){
        if(genes[j]==9){
            fitness+=.901;
        }else{
            fitness=(fitness+(1-(genes[j]+1)*.100f));
        }
    }       

    fitness = fitness/genes.length;
    fitness = Math.round(fitness *10000.0f)/10000.0f; 

    return fitness;
}
```

Comment: Maybe H-IFF could be useful to you (see page 5): https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/14b9/4407e404cd9fcf6ccdce3364b2b3092027ea.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing with a binary alphabet if you assign fitness values to groups of symbols instead of single symbols.

For example using groups of 3 symbols gives you 2^3=8 values to work with, so the same idea that you use for an alphabet 0-9 works here too.